# giving them nothing to work with to derive the next level of laws

Tags: phrase-meaning

> These worries are most acute in fundamental physics, which is not the entire subject but does play an outsized role in it. Many fret that the Large Hadron Col- lider has yet to turn up any new phenomena, **giving them nothing to work with to derive the next level of laws**. They worry whether proposed unified theories, such as string theory, can ever be tested.
> Source: Scientific American - Virtually Reality by George Musser

I understand "giving them nothing to work with to derive the next level of laws" as "which doesn't need their efforts to reach the next level of laws (that is, the next level of laws will be reached without their efforts)."  Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1):

No, you are not. But the phrase can be used a couple different ways.

> Many fret that the LHC has yet to turn up any new phenomena, giving them nothing to work with to derive the next level of laws.

"Giving them nothing to work with" in this context implies that they *were* expecting the LHC to provide useful information that *would* help them "derive the next level of laws," but since it has not, their ability to derive the laws is severely restricted and may not ever happen. If they do ever derive those laws it will not be due to the results of LHC experiments—you got that correct—but there is nothing in the paragraph that implies this *will* happen, like you say in your interpretation of the sentence.

Also, you seem to be mixing up your pronoun antecedents. "Giving *them* nothing" means *the LHC* is giving nothing to *the scientists*. The "efforts" you mention are the efforts of the LHC and the scientists running the LHC, while "them" refers to the scientists who are interpreting those results. The two groups may be the same or they may not be, but grammatically they are distinct.

If you saw a sentence that said something like

> Despite the LHC giving them nothing to work with, they will be able to derive the next level of laws.

...then your interpretation would be correct, except for the pronoun mixup mentioned earlier. But you can see that the original sentence does not contain this sense of certainty.

Comment: Thank you. But your version of interpreting the phrase "giving them nothing to work with to derive the next level of laws" was what I thought of the possibilities about the meaning.  The problem in understanding is that the part before the phrase is describing future (the LHC has yet to turn up any new phenomena) - it is this future results that led to my version.  If the writer wrote "the LHC actually failed, giving them nothing...", your version would be unambiguously clear. For now, I am still puzzled by the grammar.

Comment: The grammar of "the Large Hadron Col- lider has yet to turn up any new phenomena, giving them nothing to work with to derive the next level of laws" is more like "the Large Hadron Collider has yet to turn up any new phenomena that will give something for them to derive the next level of laws."  It might be much clearer to write like this: the Large Hadron Collider in fact failed, giving them nothing to work with to derive the next level of laws. It has yet to turn up any new phenomena for them to reach the new level."

Comment: @NewPlanet your last rewrite option is excessively wordy and not really clearer than any of the other options. Your second-to-last rewrite conveys the correct meaning.